# Post payload and receive response with AngularJs and PHP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is how I'm trying to post some JSON to the php file

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: ApiService.Url("checkout.php"), data: "My JSON payload", cache: false});
```

And this is the PHP file that I want to post to

```
<?php
// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);

// header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo "MAMAMAMAMAMAAMAMAMAMAMAMAMMA";
```

What I want is to post the payload to the PHP and then get the response, how can I do that? It's my first time using Angular, other that that I'm new to vanilla JS as well, this is all I came up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am creating a function that will post data to the server and inform you with the response.

var ajaxApp = angular.module("ajaxApp", []);

    ajaxApp.controller("CompaniesCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function($scope, 
       $http, $q) {


   // This function will take params object as a parameter, will make a post 
  //request to the server and return the promise. 

      var postData  = function (params) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var post = $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "YOUR_URL",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: params,
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            });

            post.success(function (data, status) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });

            post.error(function (data, status) {
                deferred.reject(null);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        postData().then(function(data) {
            // This function will be executed when api call is success
            console.log("Data posted");
            console.log(data);
        }, function() {
          // This function will be executed when api call fails.
            console.log("Error Occured");
        });
    }]);
```

For More information please go to this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

I hope this will help you.